# Is it possible to select for nth-descendant elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm looking to select elements by the embed level they hold in the DOM using something like `nth-child` logic. For example, rather than select each nested layer manually in the css using a unique class, I want to use nth logic to cause every other nested element down the line to alternate between two colors.

---

**CLEARLY STATED EDIT**: To select elements according to their nest level, it appears you need to create a dedicated selector for each level; [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rdEooJ). *But* what if you want to select elements according to their nesting level **indefinitely** *deep*, for example if you had a ui that calls for nested divs fifty plus levels deep, with each level needing to be alternately styled? **Is there a way to use `nth` logic**, as I have in this [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eMwxOM), **to accomplish this**?

Comment: Are you simply looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child ...?

Comment: No. nth-child selects siblings. I need to select the lineage.

Comment: Well then maybe you are looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors instead. Still guessing, because your description so far is still pretty vague. Please go read [ask], and how to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

This set of selectors will select elements according to their nesting level from  `.container`:

```
.container > * { color:red; }
.container > * > * { color:blue; }
.container > * > * > * { color:green; }
...
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: That's the point I'm trying to make. In order to select elements according to their nesting level, it appears, you need to create a dedicated selector for each level. *But* what if you want to select elements according to their nesting level **indefinitely** deep, as I have demonstrated a need for in the codepen I have provided? Is there a way to use `nth` logic to do this? Or is there any simple way without needing to create an infinite number of `.container > *` nestlevel selectors?